# Maxwell-Klein-Gordon energy estimates in Klainerman and Machedon's 1994 paper

Tags: reference-request, hyperbolic-pde, wave-equation

In the 1994 paper [On the Maxwell-Klein-Gordon Equation with Finite Energy](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.dmj/1077288008) of Klainerman and Machedon, the proof of Proposition 1.1 contains the following statement. For $\phi$ (the scalar field of) a classical solution of the Maxwell-Klein-Gordon system, if $$ \| \phi \|_{L^3(\mathbb{R}^3)} \leqslant C(1+t) \left(1 +\| \phi \|_{L^3(\mathbb{R}^3)}\right)^{1/2},  $$ then $$ \| \phi \|_{L^3(\mathbb{R}^3)} \leqslant C(1+t). $$ I don't understand how they deduce this. For a start, it certainly doesn't follow if one ignores the fact that $\phi$ solves the Klein-Gordon equation: take, for example $\phi(t,x) = t^2 \psi(x)$, where $\psi(x)$ is any $L^3(\mathbb{R}^3)$ function with unit norm. The $(1+t)$ looks like it should come from some sort of linear wave equation estimate, but there's no indication they are using anything like that in that proof! What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo in the paper. Look at the bottom two lines of page 22 which I transcribe here

\begin{align}
\|\phi\|_{L^3} & \leq \ldots \\
  & \lesssim \mathscr{I}_0^{1/2} (1+t)^{1/2} ( \mathscr{I}_0 + \|A\|_{L^6} \|\phi\|_{L^3} )^{1/2}\\
  & \lesssim \mathscr{I}_0 \color{red}{(1+t)} (1 + \|\phi\|_{L^3})^{1/2}
\end{align}

If we use Sobolev to control $\|A\|_{L^6} \lesssim \|\nabla A\|_{L^2} \lesssim \mathscr{I}_0$, to get from the second to last line to the last line, the final line should in fact have the term that I marked in red replaced by $\color{green}{(1+t)^{1/2}}$. With this (1.5.c) follows.

Comment: Ah yes, of course! Thanks for the clarification.